# Searching for '\' using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written  a following code to get just the file name without extension and path.I m running it in browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str=new String("C:\Documents and Settings\prajakta\Desktop\substr.html");
document.write(str);
var beg=str.lastIndexOf("\");// **HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT DOESNT GIVE ME THE INDEX OF '\'**
 alert(beg);
var end=str.lastIndexOf (".");
 alert(end);
document.write("<br>"+str.slice(beg+1,end));
</script>
```

but the same code code works if i replace'\' by another character ex.('p');
i m initializing var str just for ex but in my application it is not always fixed.As i m new to Javascript can any body plz tell me what is the problem?n how to solve it?

Comment: Request an editor to edit the title to reflect the escaping issue.  Mad props for fixing the text body too (spacing, caps, etc.).

Comment: Don't forget to accept one answer (the first correct or the most useful for you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash character. Use the following:

```
var beg=str.lastIndexOf("\\");
```

EDIT: Yes, it will give a -1 unless you escape the backslashes in your original string as well :)

Use this:

```
var str=new String("C:\\Documents and Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\substr.html");
```

Backslash is the Javascript escape character - this means that characters following a backslash refer to special characters. Thus, in your original string, \prajakta would be interpreted as '\p' + 'rajakta' where '\p' has a very different meaning. Thus, you need to use '`\\`' everywhere in every string.

Answer (score 1):

`"\"` is the escape character, try with `"\\"`

Anyway, I would do it with regexes, just because I like them :)

```
var str=new String("C:\\Documents and Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\substr.html");
document.write(str);
document.write("<br>"+str.replace(/^.*\\/,"").replace(/\..*?$/,""));
```

Oh, and testing I saw that you have to escape the backslashes in the test string also!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape "\" in most languages, because \ is an escape-sequence. Javascript is probably the same.

Try searching for `"\\"` (without the space) instead. Also, replace `"C:\Docume..."` with `"C:\\Documents..."` for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lastIndexOf("\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is generally the escape character, so you'll have to enter it twice whenever it occurs in a string, i.e. your

```
var str=new String("C:\Documents and Settings\prajakta\Desktop\substr.html");
```

should read

```
var str=new String("C:\\Documents and Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\substr.html");
```

The thing is, `\D` is interpreted by the javascript engine, and will be replaced by the appropriate special character (in this case, I don't believe there's a special character `\D` (or 'p' or 's'), so it'll be replaced by simply `D`, and your string contents will be

```
"C:Documents and SettingsprajaktaDesktopsubstr.html"
```

Go ahead, check it with a simple

```
if (str == "C:Documents and SettingsprajaktaDesktopsubstr.html") alert("Doh! :)");
```

it should give you the alert.

Also, your

```
var beg=str.lastIndexOf("\");
```

should read

```
var beg=str.lastIndexOf("\\");
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Before putting your string into the variable you should `escape(String)` it.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what's already said, "new String" makes no sense here

```
var str="C:\\Documents and Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\substr.html";
```

and yes, regexps are the way to go

```
fileName = str.match(/([^\\.]+)\.\w+$/)[1]
```