# Distinguish '$' and '\$' in a string using javascript indexOf method

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following data is entered by user in a text area

> test\$ing

I need to extract and modify the data. Problem is that I am not able to distinguish between '$' and '\$'

I have made the following attempts.

> `indexOf('\\')` gives -1 
>   `indexOf('\$')` gives 4
>   `indexOf('$')` gives 4
>   `charAt(4)` gives $

I understand that java script treat '\$' as a single character. But how to distinguish whether the character is '$' or '\$'

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629824/searching-for-using-javascript) and the accepted solution suggests to change the original text by escape backslashes.  Is this the only possible way? Even if this is the case, how to escape the backslashes in the original text?

Please help

Comment: `indexOf("\\$")` This creates a string with two characters, the backslash, which requires a backslash to escape it for inclusion, and the dollar sign.

Comment: @squint, tested this. indexOf("\\$") gives -1

Comment: You don't show us how you are acquiring the string.  At this point you are probably best off printing the string to a log to show EXACTLY what it contains.  I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: Then there's no backslash followed by a dollar sign in the string. If your test string looks something like `var test = "foo\$bar"`, then that string does not represent a string with the pair of characters you're looking for. It would need to be `var test = "foo\\$bar"`.

Comment: You should probably figure out the difference between the real user input and a test variable that contains a string. When assigning a string to a variable, backslash is an escape character while with the user input, it’s not.

Comment: And FYI, you can use linter tools to be informed of invalid escape sequences in strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is an escape character, which means that in order to get a literal version of that character you have to write two of them in a row. Thus, your string should be written as `'test\\$ing'` in JavaScript source. (However, users don't need to escape this character when they are typing in the context of a `<textarea>`.) To find a blackslash followed by `$` inside your string you would write:

```
string.indexOf('\\$') //=> 4
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
var string = 'test\\$ing'

console.log(string.indexOf('\\')) //=> 4
console.log(string.indexOf('\\$')) //=> 4
console.log(string.indexOf('$')) //=> 5
console.log(string.charAt(4)) //=> '\'
```

Comment: but the text is entered by the user. How to modify the original text then?

Comment: You don't need to modify the original text if it was typed by the user. You only need to escape the `'\'` when you are writing it in JavaScript source. Two backslashes in a row translates to only one backslash in your data.

Comment: thanks. it helped. i was assigning this value to a variable and testing. Therefore it was never detecting this escape character. When i directly tried with the value of the text area, i am getting the difference. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you work with a string `'test\$ing'` then you can't detect '\' because it is removed.
2. If user types `\$` inside `textarea.value`, then indexOf should work.

Please provide more code.