# Find special character in java script "\:"

Tags: javascript

In Java script, I want check if ":" is present in below string or not.I tried using indexOf() but it didn't work. Can anyone suggest on this.

"LOCAL:ABCD:1234";

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629824/searching-for-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
"LOCAL:ABCD:1234".indexOf(":") //output 5
```

to check if it is present

```
"LOCAL:ABCD:1234".indexOf(":") > -1 //outputs true
```

Comment: if i want to search "\:" in "LOCAL:ABCD\:1234" then? Basically want to search backslashand colon  in string

Comment: @gopal `"LOCAL:ABCD\:1234"` exactly similar to ` "LOCAL:ABCD:1234"` since single `\` is ignored. you need to have two backslash `\\`

Comment: hi @gurvinder, Can you provide me example

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that:

```
var yourstring = "LOCAL:ABCD:1234";
var substring = '\:';

if (yourstring.includes(substring)) {
    // Yes I Found One \:
} else {
    // No \: Found
}
```

Or you can try match function

```
if (yourstring.match(/\\:/g)) {
   // Found it ...
}
```

Or the last one:

```
if (yourstring.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
    // Found it ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, C, E;
addEventListener('load', function(){

doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var wtf = E('wtf'), out = E('out'), oS = out.style;
E('test').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var m = wtf.value.match(/\\:/);
  if(m){
    out.innerHTML = "It's a Match"; oS.color = 'green';
    // just for testing
    console.log(m);
  }
  else{
    out.innerHTML = "It's Not a Match"; oS.color = 'red';
  }
});

});
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#test{
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Escape Test</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <input id='wtf' type='text' value='what\:the\:fun' /><input id='test' type='button' value='test' />
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```